# How to perform basic server-sided operations using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, server, client, operations

I'm an old-fashioned JavaScript freelance coder that likes to code EXCLUSIVELY in the original Notepad app on Windows.

I use *older techniques*:
**EXAMPLE:** Before AJAX came around, I would replace existing content on a webpage like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>EXAMPLE</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function changeText(){
    var newText = document.body.getElementsByTagName('p');
    newText[0].innerHTML = "Goodbye";
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

...and I like to keep things **SIMPLE**.

**Now, here's my inquiry:**

For CLIENT->SERVER and SERVER->CLIENT basic communication in JavaScript:

How to send this data from the webpage to the server:

```
var x = 1;
```

And then, the server could make a comparison/calculation like this:

```
if(x==1){
    alert("The number is ONE");
}
```

Then, the server could return that result to the webpage, which is:

```
alert("The number is ONE"); //This is true
```

**^:** Then, the webpage user will see the alert message popup.

***...BUT, here's the catch!!***  I want to STORE that value of x, which is "1", into a text file on the server in order to keep a record of that variable.

**In layman's terms, I want to:**

- Send a variable from a webpage to the server
- Server will check data and perform an operation
- Server will also save that variable data in a separate text file on server
- Server will send the response back to the webpage

What is the **SIMPLEST** way that I could perform these basic actions using JavaScript?  If possible, I'd like to write it ALL in Notepad.  I'm not fond of using such apps like Dreamweaver, Notepad++, etc.

I am willing to learn JSON, JQuery, and AJAX, as it may be needed for such.

Thanks in advance, and thank you for you time! :)

Comment: if you want to use javascript on the server, look at nodejs, you can use notepad to accomplish that task

Comment: Thank you David, I have begun to look into NodeJS.....the damned console for NodeJS sucks though, giving me "..." all the time.

I wrote an example SIMPLE code in Notepad, but have no idea how to execute it:

`console.log("Hello, World!")`

...I can't even execute a simple code like this without issues.  The console is jet black, and the syntax is strict as hell.  I've been unsuccessful all day in trying to do simple operations; I guess it's just my bad luck. -_-;

Comment: look into beginner tutorial on node. check out this link http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs

Answer (score -1):

In general, you have to send the data via POST ajax as a parameter to the server. At the server you can read those POST parameters and write them to a file, database or whatever. In repsonse to that, you can handle the response how you want it.

Serverside there is a good PHP framework, which i use: http://www.slimframework.com/

Comment: Hi Disane, thank you for your suggestion.  I have looked into AJAX and have enountered **ONE CRAZY PROBLEM** :  

HERE'S MY server's .htacess file code:  
`# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /`  

HERE'S THE MAIN HTML FILE WITH THE AJAX CODE:  
[link](http://www.tripmx.netii.net/testing/ajaxtesting.html)  

HERE'S THE DATA FILE CONTENTS:  
`123`  

....I get the infamous **“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”** error.  I've read many topics here about it, but I need a SIMPLE solution.

Comment: You have to exclude all files which shouldn't be rewritten by MOD_RWRITE like this:
`# Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`

-d = directory
-f = files

Comment: So I should slap this code into my .htaccess file (I'm guessing you want me replace all the contents of the file with your suggested code?), and it'll magically allow the Access Control Allow Origin thing to allow my simple AJAX code to finally be able to perform the simple operation of 'GET'-ing three integers "123" from the text file?  

My server should all be of the same origin, as I've shown in the links in my previous response.  I'm still surprised that I'm having this much server-sided trouble for simple operations.

Comment: Just delete the .htaccess and I guess it'll work fine.